# Read HTML Response and print urls in Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

Im new to Django. Basically i have page where it has all city names, i have added them using admin page and models. Now if i click on any City name it should route to that city's wiki page. My question is how can i get the city name which i have clicked and how can i dynamically pass those city names in URLS appedning the city name to it and call individual wiki page.

Here is my html snippet of city, where dests.name is my city name

```
                       {%for dests in dests%}
                            <!-- Destination -->
                            <div class="destination item">
                                <div class="destination_image">
                                    <img src="{{dests.image.url}}" alt="">
                                    {% if dests.offer %}
                                    <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                                <div class="destination_content">
                                    <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations">{{dests.name}}</a></div>
                                    <div class="destination_subtitle">
                                        <p>{{dests.desc}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="destination_price">From ${{dests.price}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {%endfor%}
```

My present view has code to check user authentication and load sample html when clicked on city name

```
class Destinations:
    def destinations(request):
        # Login.login(request)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:

            return render(request,'sample.html')

        else:
            print("In Destinations else loop")
            return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML template would be something like this:

```
                   {%for dest in dests%}
                    <!-- Destination -->
                    <div class="destination item">
                        <div class="destination_image">
                            <img src="{{dest.image.url}}" alt="">
                            {% if dest.offer %}
                            <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a 
                             href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="destination_content">
                            <div class="destination_title"><a 
                             href="{% url 'destination_detail' dest.name %}">{{dest.name}}</a></div>
                            <div class="destination_subtitle">
                                <p>{{dest.desc}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="destination_price">From 
                            ${{dest.price}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {%endfor%}
```

And create a url as follows for your detail view.

```
path('destination/<str:city>', destination, name='destination_detail'),
```

And in your view function `destination`, you can obtain the city send through the url from

```
kwargs['city']
```

You can change your view method to the following:

```
def destinations(request, *args, **kwargs):

    destination_city = kwargs[‘city’]
```

You can then use this `destination_city` anywhere you want, this will have the value coming from the url.

Comment: I didnt understand how to write view function for this

Comment: Il expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Arun T, i made modifications to my code as you suggested, now im not able to see my city name on HTML to click, i.e., this part of code <div class="destination_title"><a  href="{% url 'destination_detail' dests.name %}">{{dests.name}}</a></div>

Comment: Also this is how my view is right now, 
class Destinations(Traveller):
    def destinations(request, url, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print("user is authenticated")
            destination_city = kwargs['city']
            print(destination_city)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('destination_detail')

Comment: Shouldnt it be {{ dest.name }} dests is the whole list right?

Comment: Actually yes, before i paste this here it was dests there, now i changed to dest.name but not no luck

Comment: my html page and views file added as answer as it has too many characters

Answer (score 0):

my html

```
{%for dest in dests%}
                            <!-- Destination -->
                            <div class="destination item">
                                <div class="destination_image">
                                    <img src="{{dest.image.url}}" alt="">
                                    {% if dest.offer %}
                                    <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                                <div class="destination_content">
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <div class="destination_title"><a  href="{% url 'destination_detail' dest.name %}">{{dests.name}}</a></div>

                                {%endif%}   
                                    <div class="destination_subtitle">
                                        <p>{{dest.desc}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="destination_price">From ${{dest.price}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {%endfor%}
```

and views.py

```
class Traveller:
    def travellerView(request):
        dests=Destination.objects.all()
        return render(request,'travellerapp/index.html',{'dests':dests})

class Destinations(Traveller):
    def destinations(request, url, *args, **kwargs):
        # Login.login(request)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print("user is authenticated")
            destination_city = kwargs['city']
            print(destination_city)




            #print(request.)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('destination_detail')
        else:
            print("User is not authenticated, hence logging in now")
            return redirect('login')
```

Comment: this line `<div class="destination_title"><a  href="{% url 'destination_detail' dest.name %}">{{dests.name}}</a></div>` should be `<div class="destination_title"><a  href="{% url 'destination_detail' dest.name %}">{{dest.name}}</a></div>`

Comment: Also since u have added `if user.is_authenticated` are you opening this view with an authenticated user?

Comment: Yes Arun, im using valid user  authentication for this, i have three different buttons on my UI register, login and if user logins logout. Right now what is happening is i click on any button it goes to Login only, just trying to figure out what is going wrong